# Redirecting to specific websites using error 301

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have two domain names bought mainly for SEO, I want to redirect them to certain pages on website of a different domain name.

I know I need to redirect them with 301's in the `.htaccess`.

But I'm getting confused, do I need to create essentially 3 `.htaccess` files one on each domain?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you only need **one** `.htaccess` file **per domain**. However, be wary of including or excluding the `www.` in your URL, as you may render your SEO useless.

**Redirecting to a non `www.` URL:**

This assumes you are using Apache or something similar.
Open your existing `.htaccess` file using a text editor, and append the following code to it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1
[R=301,L]
```

Where `example.com/` is your domain. As far as I am aware, you can append any page to this URL with the same effect.

**Redirecting to a `www.` URL:**

Again, assuming Apache or similar:
Open your `.htaccess` file in the text editor, and append:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1
[R=301,L]
```

Again, `example.com/` refers to your own domain. Again, AFAIK you can append specific pages without issue.

With most websites, `www.example.com` and `example.com` will take you to the same place. If you haven't made any changes to this, I would advise using the former example.

Additionally, if you are using Wordpress, there are a vast number of different plugins that can handle this for you. For example (and I am not recommending this over any other plugin), https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/

You may also hear the code`rel="canonical"` or see it from time-to-time. Some SEO professionals actually recommend this over 301, however with modern browsers and modern crawlers, this should no longer be an issue.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't  sure if I needed .htaccess files for the other domains

Comment: For each domain that you want to point to another, you will need one `.htaccess`. That means that the two domains you have bought will need an `.htaccess` each, but you needn't worry about the existing domain if it is already in a working state.